# Google Drive stopped working

Tags: google-drive, cloud

I have installed Google Drive app on my PC, and it ran fine, but now whenever I open it, it displays error.

[image: Screenshot of error]

I have tried to exit and run again multiple times and also deinstall and install, but error repeats.

Comment: Wow. That's an detailed error message. (Not)

Comment: How to give more precise error? :)

Comment: No, I'm not directing that at you; I'm giving Google a hard time:) I don't think you can get a more detailed error.

Comment: Because the error message is utterly useless, just try uninstalling and reinstalling google drive